# Building Jenkins fails

Tags: jenkins

1. Did a git clone https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins.git
2. cd jenkins
3. mvn install

I am getting the below error.

`

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\jenkins\cli\target\classes\META-INF\annotations\org.kohsuke.accmod.Restricted
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Jenkins main module 2.142-SNAPSHOT ................. SUCCESS [  2.720 s]
[INFO] Jenkins cli ........................................ FAILURE [  1.985 s]
[INFO] Jenkins core ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Jenkins war ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Tests for Jenkins core 2.142-SNAPSHOT .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.255 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-18T23:34:03-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.2:compile (default-compile) on project cli: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\jenkins\cli\target\classes\META-INF\annotations\org.kohsuke.accmod.Restricted
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cli
```

`

Any idea why the mvn install is failing on a project downloaded directly from stash.

Comment: Are you using Java 9 or Java 10?

Comment: @S.Spieker I am using Java 10

Comment: I think jenkins is not yet compatible with java 10: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40689 or: https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/06/08/jenkins-java10-hackathon/